# Uninstall Visual studio 2013 update 1 rc

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

In fear of sounding like a noob;

I'm having troubles uninstalling visual studio 2013 update 1.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to "Control Panel" -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> On the left bar "View installed updates". Then scroll down to "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 1"

Comment: Just used the approach to kill VS update 3. However, the bad thing is that it kills ALL updates. I.e. uninstalling update 3 did not restore me to update 2 - it returned me to base VS2013 (prior to update 1) :(

Comment: @Serge gah, really? This time to, what are they up to over there at Redmond! I was just about to upgrade myself here, but I'm away and well my main box needs a clean install anyways.. But this is just sad.

Comment: When uninstalling Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, it displays a warning about this: "An earlier version of this update is required by Visual Studio 2013. To ensure that Visual Studio runs correctly after uninstall, select Visual Studio on the installed programs page in the Control Panel and then choose Repair."

Answer (score 6):

ok.. now I feel stupid, I looked here first, but didn't find it ;) Sigh my eyes was in the was I guess ;)

[image: Program and features.....]

Answer (score 1):

I have had a few issues with uninstalling VS 2013. For some reasons, I had to use this version as I had some codes which could be only compiled with version. After uninstallation, it damaged my icons and etc. The only way, I could get rid of it was to do system restore. I know it's a pain in the neck but that's a safer approach.