# Not able to install VS-2013 with update 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation

When I install visual studio I get below error. I tried multiple times but it's failing all the time. Knidly help me here.

[image]

Log file: [Log file with error](https://paste.ee/p/uZFsB)

Comment: I had a similar issue where Update 3 wasn't installing. I found uninstalling updates 1 and 2 and reinstalling them manually along with update 3 fixed the issue. Was a pain, but ended up working in the end.

Comment: Here is the thing. I am installing it afresh. I do not have previous updates and all. I have got the iso file from my manager along with the keys and all. I just extracted it and tried to install.

Comment: Is it not letting you open up VS? You should be able to open it still, if you can't find the application launcher check your program files.

Comment: [Link to help with uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632694/uninstall-visual-studio-2013-update-1-rc)

Comment: I am able to launch it though. But I don't know where this issue will create problem when I am developing the code. And having problem in VS is the last thing I want when I get a bug during a code work. I will be thinking it's becaue of my code and will be banging my head and it will be from VS. I hope you got my point.

Comment: So, do I need to worry about this error or not. Or as I am able to launch can I go ahead and start using it?

Comment: use VS2013 ISo with update 5 and not the older update3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two error messages in your log file as below:

1. *Applied non-vital package: trintrir_71, encountered error: 0x80070643*, the error code ‘**0x80070643**’ is a general, since you used the ISO file to install, you can verify the integrity of it. Using [the FCIV.exe tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2011/03/25/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing/) to check the SHA1 value of the ISO, the expected value comes from [VS 2013 SHA-1 Value](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2013-sha-vs#proU3), any discrepancy means the ISO is corrupted. After that, you can manually install [the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54251) to solve this issue.
2. *Applied non-vital package: vsupdate_kb2829760, encountered error: **0x80044000***, for the error code, we can have a look at this: [Error in installation log for Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC can be misleading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2014/04/17/error-in-installation-log-for-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-can-be-misleading/), you can try to re-run the VS installer to repair it. Or go to Tools-Extensions and updates-Updates, now the latest updates for VS 2013 is VS 2013 update 5, you can find it under Updates tab, click it to install.

Meanwhile, there has some installation tips you can have a look: windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up %temp% folder and re-run the VS installer as administrator.

Comment: Here is the thing, As you see in the image it says: set up complete, so I opened the VS and did the step 2 that you told. It says now - update 5 successfully done". So is that it, can I ignore the first warning/error. Is there an way I can see even if VS is running it still has some error in it. Or since its successfully got updated to "update - 5". I can put rest of the stuff to back burner? please guide me

Comment: @Unbreakable, if you not got any warning or error message during the installation of VS 2013 update 5, it looks like you already successfully install VS professional 2013 with update 5. To verify it, you can go to Control Panel-Programs and Features, right click the VS professional 2013 with update 5 and Change-Repair, if the repair is successful, which means your VS professional 2013 with update 5 is integrity and the first warning already be fixed.

Comment: Hi Unbreakable, does your issue is solved or not? If not, you can update the current warning or error message in here.